# Compound columns evaluation in DynamicJasper

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-jasper

I use JRXML template and **dynamic** input parameters as inputs to generate advanced JRXML. Later this JRXML is taken and handled by JasperServer. The main idea is to let user pick any columns he wants and customize them.

DynamicJasper provides good API for building custom columns but I faced an issue with compound columns.

For example a user wants his column 'A' would calculated as:

```
$F{INSTRUMENT} + " (" + $F{SECURITY_IDENTIFIER} + ")"
```

or

```
$F{QUANTITY} == null ?0:$F{QUANTITY}.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)
```

so after proceed the output JRXML would have records under its details/band tag like this:

```
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement key="DK_Instrument" x="0" y="0" width="184" height="12">
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{INSTRUMENT} + " (" + $F{SECURITY_IDENTIFIER} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
<textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
    <reportElement key="DK_Quantity" x="220" y="0" width="56" height="12">
    </reportElement>
    <textElement/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{QUANTITY} == null ?0:$F{QUANTITY}.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

An *AbstractColumn* in DynamicJasper has this methods:

```
setColumnProperty(fieldName, className)
setCustomExpression(CustomExpression)
setCustomExpressionForCalculation(CustomExpression)
```

but non of them works for me.

When DynamicJasper generates JasperReport it tries to match those string to the existing fields and at this point fails since the strings contain compound items.

Any ideas/suggestion would be great.

Comment: Can you provide the working sample to reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by implementing **CustomColumn**

```
public class DynamicColumn extends AbstractColumn {
    ...

    @Override
    public String getTextForExpression() {
        return getColumnProperty().getProperty();
    }
    @Override
    public String getValueClassNameForExpression() {
        return getColumnProperty().getValueClassName();
    }
}
```

The problem was that all existing implementations of *AbstractColumn* assume a single parameter passed to the column property and it covers the parameter with *$F{...}*. By overriding *textForExpression* the property successfully goes to the output JRXML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JRDesignTextField](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignTextField.html) and [JRDesignExpression](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/design/JRDesignExpression.html)  classes for this.

```
JRDesignTextField textField = new JRDesignTextField();
JRDesignExpression expression = new JRDesignExpression();
expression.setText("$F{INSTRUMENT} + \"( \" + $F{SECURITY_IDENTIFIER} +\" ) \"");
//or expression.setText("$F{QUANTITY} == null ?0:$F{QUANTITY}.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)");
textField.setExpression(expression);
```

I think this will help you.
Check syntax, I didn't run the code, but it will give you idea.

Comment: Yes, this would work. But the thing is I don't want to get into it, I'd rather leave this work for Jasper. And the only thing I want is to tell to _DynamicJasper_ which columns should be used in run time.